# Decrypt strings encrypted with a SecretKey, when the key is no longer accessible

Tags: android, encryption

I have an interesting situation here. My app stores sensitive info input by the user such as a social service account of theirs. I use a master password input by the user to generate a SecretKey, and then use AES encryption and store its SHA1 hash and the encrypted data on device, but not the master password itself or the key.

The issue is that in case the user forgets their password, there is a secret question they can answer and change the master password. So when the master pass is changed, since the previous password (and the associated SecretKey) are forever gone, I can't decrypt the stored strings and show the decrypted data to the user.

Here are the solutions I can think of:

1 - Store the password, which I have heard is totally unsafe.

2 - Store the SecretKey, but I have heard this is unsafe too.

3 - Store user data in database unencrypted, which is unsafe I guess.

4 - Wipe the entire database everytime the user forgets their password, which is silly I think.

I need a way to overcome this and I simply can't think of a secure way to pull it off. 
It is crucial that this be solved for my app to fly. Any and all help is really appreciated.

Comment: 1. Correct. 2. Correct. 3. Correct. 4. No, this is the right answer. By definition, everything else is a backdoor. Encourage the users to use a password safe, so that they do not forget the password.

Comment: Well it's a bit unfair to remove all of user's data just because they forgot a password. My app contains their credit cards, social media accounts and some personal notes. It would be a disaster to have them deleted. in case a user relies totally on this app to save them.
Isn't there any other way to decrypt the data?? Or make the same SecretKey as before?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Well it's a bit unfair to remove all of user's data just because they forgot a password.

Then they shouldn't be storing stuff in a container that requires a passphrase. Next, you'll argue that anyone should be able to open any wall safe using a hockey ticket stub and some chewing gum, because somebody might forget the combination for the lock.

Please note that your line of inquiry assumes that the approach described in your opening paragraph is the correct way to build the app that has the security characteristics that you desire.

For example, the right answer to meet your requirements is to not encrypt the data at all, but instead force the user to have their device full-disk encrypted. You can use `DevicePolicyManager` to see if the device has full-disk encryption enabled, and you can refuse to run if they do not. Then, the data is encrypted, as is the rest of their device, but you are no longer having to deal with passphrases and recovery scenarios — that's up to Google and device manufacturers.

> Isn't there any other way to decrypt the data?

Only if you have a vulnerability in your app (a.k.a., a backdoor). This is the ticket-stub-and-chewing-gum scenario. The point behind encrypting data is to make it so that it cannot be encrypted without the passphrase or equivalent security key.

So, another approach to your app is to dump all your key stuff and use `KeyStore`. Particularly on devices with a hardware-backed `KeyStore`, there's no way to really get at the key, short of unlocking the device. Here, you don't have to worry about the full-disk encryption (as you're encrypting the data) and you also don't have to worry about the user forgetting the key (because the user never has the key). It also saves you having to have the user enter a passphrase. But now you can't readily back up the data (as it's useless without the key), and if the user's device is run over by a bakery truck or otherwise destroyed, the data is gone. You could provide options for the user to back up their key (e.g., to removable media), but now you are reliant upon them remembering where they stored the backup, storing the backup key securely, etc.

> Or make the same SecretKey as before?

Since nobody but you knows how you are creating this, nobody but you can answer your question.

I would also suggest that you read [this paper](https://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~chris/research/doc/ccs13_cryptolint.pdf), as it outlines how 88% of Android apps that they surveyed, who tried to cobble together their own crypto approach, screwed it up.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough reply.